# How to update my dictionary with user input and save it for everytime?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, user-input, chatbot

I am trying to build my own self-learning chatbot (without importing anything) and the problem which I faced was this:

If a user asks something for which the chatbot has no answer, it will update its dictionary with the question asked by the user. The chatbot will ask the answer of that question from the user itself(to learn) and store the answer too..

I used this method-

```
dict_name[question]=answer
```

I found a problem. Before stopping the program, if I ask the question again, it will give me the answer which it learnt.

However, if I stop the program and rerun it and then ask the same question, it still asks me the answer(all of the things which I taught in the previous run gets forgotten).

Is there any way I can make my bot remember what I taught it in it's previous run???

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to save your dictionary in a pickle file like this:

```
dictionary_data = {"a": 1, "b": 2}

a_file = open("data.pkl", "wb")
pickle.dump(dictionary_data, a_file)
a_file.close()

a_file = open("data.pkl", "rb")
output = pickle.load(a_file)
print(output)
```

Now you can load you dictionary every time from the file and then update before closing.

Although you would need to `import pickle`

Other alternative is dumping in json. It is almost same way, but in that case also you need to `import json`

Comment: There is still a problem. I am using the pickle method but still i cannot store the changes made to my dictionary :(

Comment: You nee to use the if statements at the begining which will directly fetch the dicitonary from the pickle file if the pickle file is there, and create a new dictionary if the pickle file is not there

Answer (score 0):

Re-running the same program will not take us to the same execution context.
Before exit, You should have stored the map (either to a file or Data base) and initialise the map with the store infomration on every start.
If you are thinking about going with file approach.. you can find sample [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/object_oriented_python/object_oriented_python_serialization.htm#:%7E:text=Pickle,a%20working%20Python%20object%20hierarchy.)